# Why is LaTeX not displaying correctly?

Tags: bug, mathjax

In this answer
[On a proof of the existence of tubular neighborhoods.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54799/on-a-proof-of-the-existence-of-tubular-neighborhoods/58124#58124)
and Neil Strickland's answer here
[Is the counit of geometric realization a Serre fibration?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/134603/is-the-counit-of-geometric-realization-a-serre-fibration)
the laTex is not displaying correctly (in Firefox version 21.0). Oddly, it looks fine after I click the edit button.  Anyone know what's going on?  In the second case, I'm pretty sure it looked fine earlier today, before the upgrade.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see this. I [asked](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/24/6085) essentially the same, with another example.

Comment: I have been using backticks a lot in answers, questions and comments and now they render incorrectly. Will it be possible to fix this problem automatically? There are too many of them to do it by hand.

Comment: If I remember the original discussion, the backticks *were* supposed to be fixed automatically. Did something go wrong?

Comment: For example my answer http://mathoverflow.net/questions/104866/brown-representability-for-non-connected-spaces/105049#105049 is completely messed up. I'm not sure whether this is a problem with backticks. I think I used them when I wrote this answer but I don't see them when I look up the source now.

Answer (score 3):

Weirdly, I managed to fix [Neil Strickland's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/134629/1) by editing it to remove whitespace from the end of the post.

Comment: That trick also worked to fix bad latex on http://mathoverflow.net/questions/134405/a-question-in-fourier-analysis

Answer (score 2):

I fixed your answer by removing the backticks and changing the backslash-brackets to double-dollar-signs. I think the new system doesn't play nicely with backslash-brackets.

EDIT: See also the discussion [here](http://mathoverflow.tqft.net/discussion/1424/mo-20-latex-issues/).

Comment: Thanks for fixing it!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another question which doesn't display correctly (but whose preview on editing does):  [Algebraic closure as a fibrant replacement?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/111862/algebraic-closure-as-a-fibrant-replacement)

Comment: Apparently the underscore in the subscript `\mathfrak{m}_i` was interpreted as the beginning of an `_italics_` sentence. I was able to fix it by surrounding the subscript by braces, i.e., writing `\mathfrak{m}_{i}` instead.

Comment: @Martin: Can you try your magic on this question, too: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/134142/ ? The problem seems similar.

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler: The magic is to make any sort of a trivial edit to the post (such as adjusting whitespace), then it takes care of itself.

Comment: @Emil: I see. Thanks for fixing it!