# What is wrong with the tag excerpts?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

Looking at the list of tags https://mathoverflow.net/tags it seems that all the tags are surrounded by html `<p>...</p>`. This seems to be happening because the html `<p>...</p>` was put directly into the tag excerpts themselves (see https://mathoverflow.net/edit-tag-wiki/443 for example). Why is that? Is it supposed to be this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a result of rerendering post bodies.  It has been fixed up.

Answer (score 2):

I added some of those tag descriptions earlier today, and they definitely did not have the `<p>`'s then. I baselessly speculate this might be related to [this](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/220/1) fix.