# Backticks breaking MathJax in comments

Tags: bug, mathjax, comments

The backticks that were used to circumvent MathJax problems on MO 1.0 were removed [in questions and answers](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/175/29555).

However, it appears that the comments were not affected by this fix and thus display MathJax as `code`, see for instance [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/126682/29555), [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/130208/a-johnson-lindenstrauss-lemma-for-finite-fields/130217#comment335470_130217) or [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/132609/almost-projective-banach-space-complex-scalars#comment342112_132609).

Would it be possible to remove those backticks that were used on MO 1.0 to fix rendering issues?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure whether it's all fixed in questions & answers either:

[positive elements in tensor products](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/43138/positive-elements-in-tensor-products/43198#43198)

This one has a backticked

```
\[ ... \]
```

construct. Replacing the backticks helps but doesn't completely solve the issue; apparently some parts of these constructs end up in textmode anyway, for whatever reason (e. g., remove the backticks from his first matrix and you'll see that the "a=" part is still textmode).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I think the construct should be `\\[ ... \\]` in order to disambiguate the displayed math environment from an escaped opening bracket. Doing this, the preview looks fine.